# A confusing problem of `snprintf()` without adding `'0'`

Tags: c++, printf, qt5.9

I came across a confusing problem involving snprintf() when using qt5.6 with (mingw 5.3.0 32bit) on win10.

My code is as follows:

```cpp
char *my3DesCBC_Decode_default(char *in_24char_CipherTxt,
                               char *out_32char_PlainTxt) {
  int xLen = 24; // default:24;
  int len001 = 0;
  unsigned char *res_PlainTxt;
  unsigned char *res_decode_Base64;

  base64_de((unsigned char *)in_24char_CipherTxt, &res_decode_Base64, &xLen);

  if (des_decode(DES3_CBC, pmingKey16_default, pmingKeyLen_default,
                 pmingVI008_default, res_decode_Base64, &res_PlainTxt,
                 &xLen) == RESULT_OK) {

    xLen = xLen > 30 ? 30 : xLen; // `xLen`: true length of decrypted string
    snprintf(out_32char_PlainTxt, xLen + 0, "%s", res_PlainTxt); // problem from this line
    len001 = strlen(out_32char_PlainTxt);
    printf("3DES CBC DECODE:%s ;Len=%d,%d\n", out_32char_PlainTxt, xLen,
           len001);
  }
}
```

The line `snprintf(out_32char_PlainTxt, xLen + 0, "%s", res_PlainTxt);` works. However, according to the document, `xLen + 0` here should be `xLen + 1`. When I use `xLen + 1`, it raised an error, to make it run again, I have to write

```cpp
snprintf(out_32char_CipherTxt,xLen+1,"%s",res_encode_Base64);
\*(out_32char_CipherTxt + xLen) = '\0';
```

More specifically, `xLen + 1` should be right because there needs another bit to store the eof `'\0'` that is added by `snprintf()` automatically. I wonder why I have to add `'\0'` by myself ? Is there any trap of `snprintf()` on different platforms ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. Please also keep in mind that it [is not possible to "help you"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/) here as this is **not a discussion forum**.

Comment: "won't add '\0'" ??  You are adding `0`, why did you pre-pend it with a back-slash ? Why did you conclude that the zero is not added ?

Comment: He just encountered a network error, not mean to do that. And he just asked me to help him to improve the question. Could you please consider to reopen it?

Comment: Voted to re-open, but the question is still unclear ...  (and luckily edit can be done when the question is closed... )

Comment: Thank you Luuk, as a matter of his work, his materials are in the virtual machine, so the network is not ideal. I already told him to prepare it well enough before resubmitting.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a C++ programmer, but may I suggest to create a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  char input [25] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx";
  char output [100] ;
  printf("strlen: %d\n", (int)sizeof(input));

  printf("snprintf: %d\n", snprintf( output, 10, input));
  printf("input: %s\n", input);
  printf("output: %s\n", output);

  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
strlen: 25
snprintf: 24
input: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx
output: abcdefghi
```

When second parameter is 10, the results will be 9 character long (`abcdefghi`).

**(My) conclusion**:

When you have a problem using:

```
snprintf(out_32char_PlainTxt, xLen + 0, "%s", res_PlainTxt); // problem from this line
```

and the problem is that the result is 1 character too small, then you can use `xLen + 1`.

But this seems pretty standard C++, (and I repeat myself:) I am not a C++ programmer!